# If evaluation of incremented value

Tags: perl

I am trying to catch the case where my value is not initialized and I increment it. From what I read, `$value` will act based on context (if I concatenate it, it will act as empty string, if I increment it, it will act as `0`).

What I don't understand is why the code above gives me :
`The value outside of the if: 1` and it doesn't also show: `The value from if: 1`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $value;

if (( $value++) == 1){
    print "The value from if: $value";
}

print "The value outside of the if: $value";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the *post increment* form of the [`auto-increment operator`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Auto-increment-and-Auto-decrement)

> "++" and "--" work as in C. That is, if placed before a variable, they increment or decrement the variable by one before returning the value, and if placed after, increment or decrement after returning the value.

So the value prior to increment is returned first and that is used in the statement, thus the condition is evaluated with it and found to be false. The incremented value is used the next time the variable is evaluated. With `++$value` it will do what you expect.  This is clearly a little tricky, to say the least.

Note that the string-vs-number magic that you mention works for increment only, *not* decrement operator.  See the above `perlop` page.

Comment: Well, I thought it won't evaluate until it gets out of the paranthesis scope. Thank you!

Comment: @JohnDoe  My previous response was needlessly complicated.  The value is returned right away, but it is the value _before_ the increment (while the incremented value is saved away).  Thus that  value is used in the whole statement. I am adjusting the answer to clarify this.

Comment: Note that even a post increment will return the *autovivified* value before the increment. That is, if `$value` is `undef` then `$value++` will be *zero*.

Comment: @Borodin  That is a part of the "magic" available with increment -- I didn't realize that it is "_autovivification_", thank you.

Comment: The pre-increment is almost always what is wanted. However, because of the name of the language C++, it is the post-increment that is the most common. `++$value` makes a lot more sense to read, because the "verb" precedes the variable. It also takes additional steps to save the original value, so `$value--` is slightly slower, and may even be so if the return value isn't used if the compiler doesn't optimise properly. The moral is to *always* use the pre-increment unless you are in the unusual situation of needing the post-increment variation.

Comment: Yes, if `$value` is `undef` then `$value->[0] = 1` or `push @$value, 1` will autovivify an empty array and put a reference to it into `$value`, likewise `$value->{key} = 1` will create an empty hash. If you `open $value, 'file'` then a file glob is created and a reference to it stored. The same thing happens if you try to increment an undefined variable or append a string to it: a value of zero or the empty string is created and assigned to the variable so that the operation can go ahead. All of these are autovivication.

Comment: @Borodin  I completely agree and generally use `++i` in C++. I think that this is a very important comment, since most Perl code that I see uses post-increment.  However, i find this use so dominant in Perl that I end up going along with it (fearing complications I guess).

Comment: @Borodin  My comments came out of order -- thank you for these examples/explanations of autovivification!  Very interesting, and educational.

Comment: Thank you @Borodin for the explanations!